# Help required to convert georeferenced (and rectified) TIFF orthophotos to georeferenced .JPG format

Tags: georeferencing

I am not a GIS specialist (so patience required!) :) We work with georeferenced, rectified 1:10 000 orthophotos. I need help with the conversion of a georeferenced tiff to a georeferenced jpg.

Our recently acquired JUNO (Trimble) GPS's work very well with an eventual conversion of jpg to ecw format - but I first need help in converting my tiff files to jpg.

Any ideas please? Free/shareware or products for sale that you know of?
thanks!
Monique

Comment: Are these Tiffs with tfw [world files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) or [GeoTiffs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotiff) with the georeferencing embedded in it?  If the former, there are likely many TIF->JPG translation programs you could use and just copy the .tifw file to a .jpgw file.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps the easiest way is to use the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org) tools, which underpin many GIS and mapping systems out there. If you're dealing with lots of files, it is a fairly easy task to write a batch file or script to automate the process.

I'll make some assumptions here about your level of comfort with the command line, but hopefully it should be easy to follow.

First, obtain GDAL. For most Linux distros, there should be a package in your repository. For Windows, it is easiest to download either [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/) or [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).

Next, you need to run the program `gdal_translate` which will do the actual hard work for you. For your needs, it is a fairly simple set of options:

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG -co "WORLDFILE=YES" <source_filename>.tif <dest_filename>.jpg
```

This just tells GDAL to output a JPEG image given your source file and a destination filename. It will create two files, the JPEG image itself, and a .jpw (or possibly .wld) file which contains the georeferencing information, without which it would just be a picture.

Answer (score 5):

[GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) is your friend.  You can use [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to do it, something like this:

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG input.tif output.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

I utilize Autodesk Raster Design.
It has many great features. However not free.
Also required are Autocad Map 3d.